# JQuery UI dialog confirmation pass variable and actions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to pass a variable to a **Jquery Ui dialog** confirmation box to do something
when press YES and only close the dialog when press No.
Now I have this code

```
$("#confirmDialog" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    'OK': function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    'Cancel': function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
 });


$(".confirm").click(function(){

var myHref = $(this).attr("href");

   $("#confirmDialog").dialog( "open" ).html ( "Confirm?" )
   $("#confirmDialog").on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) { window.location = myHref } );
   return false;
});
```

For now I found only the function on("dialogclose") and nothing else.
How can I set the ui dialog to do something when the user press YES?
I tried to pass the variable as well but without success

```
$(".confirm").click(function(){    
$("#confirmDialog").attr(myHref).dialog( "open" ).html ( "Confirm?" )
return false;
}); 

$("#confirmDialog" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    'OK': function() {
        window.location.href = myHref;
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    'Cancel': function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
     });
```

or

```
$("#confirmDialog").dialog( "open" ).html ( "Confirm?" )
$("#confirmDialog").on( "OK", function( event, ui ) { window.location = myHref } );
```

how can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You would have to write an extension method. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to set some value when user clicks ok inside the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it so your ok button click (inside the dialog), calls a function which uses the variable you want to set. You then set that variable inside the link click event, then display the dialog for confirmation.

For example:

```
    var $dialog = $( '#dialog-confirm' );
var $button = $('#linkButton');
var link = '';

// init dialog

$dialog.dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:340,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      doSomething(); // reference your function here
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});

// bind event

$button.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  link = $(this).attr('href');
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});

function doSomething(){
  window.location = link;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/azezal/2/

Code view here: http://jsbin.com/azezal/2/edit

Comment: thank but I would like to use a link not a button, and I would like to use the href attribute to set my link variable. I tried so  $(".del").click(function(){
   link = $(this).attr("href"); 
      $dialog.dialog('open');
    }); but does not work :(

Comment: The code is actually very similar, I have updated my answer. Hopefully that's right :)